# Transformation of equation system with additional constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I'm stuck with the following problem:
$$
\text{Let}\\
A, B \in  \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} \text{ and } \hat{c}, \hat{f}, \hat{\alpha}, \hat{\beta} \in \mathbb{C}^n
\\
\text{Find }\\
\underline{\mathbf{x}}, \underline{\mathbf{y}} \in \mathbb{C}^{n} \text{ such that}\\
A \underline{\mathbf{x}} = B \underline{\mathbf{y}} + \hat{c}\\
\textbf{and}\\
\hat{\alpha}_i \underline{\mathbf{x}}_i + \hat{\beta}_i \underline{\mathbf{y}}_i = \hat{f}_i, i = 1,...,n
$$
The matrices $A$ and $B$ are discretized integral operators, $\hat{c}, \hat{f}, \hat{\alpha}, \hat{\beta}$ are boundary conditions and $\underline{\mathbb{x}}, \underline{\mathbb{y}}$ are the solution vectors.
I want to transform the abovementioned equation system into a simple $C z = d$ equation system and determine the solution vectors $\underline{\mathbf{x}}, \underline{\mathbf{y}}$ afterwards.
Unfortunately, I could not find any similar questions or in general literature that deals with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following notations,
$$
\hat A = \text{diag}(\hat\alpha) ,\quad \hat B = \text{diag}(\hat\beta) ,
$$
the previous system of equations can be rewritten as
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A & -B \\
\hat A & \hat B
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
{\bf x}\\
{\bf y}
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\hat c\\
\hat f
\end{array}
\right] .
$$

Comment: Your solution is absolutely correct, thank you!
But I guess $\hat{A} = diag(\hat{\alpha}_i)$ should rather be $\hat{A} = diag(\hat{\alpha})$ because $i$ just denotes the corresponding entry in the vector?